# Would it be possible / usefull to add syntax checkers to SO?

Tags: feature-request

It sometimes (quite often with new users) happens that users ask why their code isn't working. After reviewing the code in question, it turns out there's simply one or more syntax errors causing the issue.

It also sometimes happens that a code is so full of syntax errors, that trying to help the Question Owner to solve the problem, would require rewriting half the users code.

Looking around at the web, there are several websites that can check code for syntax errors and tell you if something (and what) is wrong.

Wouldn't it be usefull for both the one asking the question as well as those trying to answer it, to directly be able to see if there are any syntax errors inside the code? Perhaps something like a small red hyperlink or "hover over link" underneath the code that says:

> xx number of issues found.

Once hovered over it could explain in more detail what those issues are. I'd like to hear your ideas or opinion about as to why this would be usefull or not and if it's even possible to add such a feature to SO?

Comment: No. I rather feel that almost all OPs must have some language-processing software available to them. Why suck up SE's CPU-time? What about licensing paid-for software? What about getting the exact version/release? I've done no research, but from buggy code which a language-processor should spot, it has always been typos made during formulation of the question. Just comment for the real code.

Comment: @BillWoodger Honestly, I didn't think about the resources it would require from SE. I guess technically it would be possible for a user to select which version (s)he is using, but that would just lead to even more drain because of all the extra "version"-checkers needed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stack Overflow should not do this, ever.

It's impossible to get right on the technical end - what about different versions, dialects, etc. of a language, constructs that are declared somewhere else in the code, etc.

But even if it *were* possible, it would be a bad idea.

- There would be loads of false positives. We encourage OPs to post as little code as necessary to understand the problem. This can often mean a fractured piece of code which a syntax checker would then complain about.
- It would send the wrong signal to users, telling them that it is ok to turn  to Stack Overflow immediately when something is wrong, instead of doing their due diligence.

What we should be teaching users with syntax problems is how to navigate to the nearest proper code validation service available for the language, or how to use an IDE or other tool that can check syntax on the fly.

Comment: Ofcourse. I understand why this would never work. Thanks :)

Comment: @icecub sure. Don't worry about the downvotes by the way, they are normal on Meta as indicators of disagreement - and it is good this was asked and can be discussed, because someone else is going to come up it again in the future :)

Comment: Oh I'm not, haha. That's why I left the question in place. I didn't find it on Meta anywhere and I think this is a good one to keep around.

Comment: And how to read and understand diagnositic messages, which I think is the most important as due to the version/release/dialect issue with IDE/site-for-checking-some-syntax-but-not-necessarily-yours